# Strange $http POST Angularjs clarification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, spring, rest

HI in my web development i'm finding a strange issue, i'm having an entire table as input field where users enter data and send back to Spring Rest, i'm getting the data as String and parsing it using Gson library

```js
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'saveTableData.do',
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;'},
     data:'tableVal'+data1
 }) ;
```

and my Spring controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveTableData",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveTableDataToDb(@RequestBody String tableData) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    TableData dataFromJson = gson.fromJson(tableData, TableData.class);
}
```

the issue is data is being sent to backend but in console i'm getting 
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Why is this and will it impact in future

Comment: try changing url to `/SaveTableData`

Comment: should be /saveTableData, being lower case 's'?

Comment: @entre nope! no use any other solutions

Comment: where is your spring response for the  http call

Comment: was using @resposeody for long time totally forgot this return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a Spring user, but my bet would be that the 404 comes from you not returning anything back from your method.

In dummy code I would expect something like this:

```
public Response saveTableDataToDb(MyVar myvar) {
    // Do some smart business logic
    Response resp = new Response();
    resp.setResultCode(200) //http for everything ok, or whatever you need
    return resp;
}
```

Like I said I don't really know Spring but that would be my bet since you have a void method at the moment.